# DocumentQueryException: Query expression is invalid

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to query a collection in cosmosdb.

My entity is:

```
 public class Tenant
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }

        public string TenantDomainUrl { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public string SiteCollectionTestUrl { get; set; }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

And my controller action is:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Tenant/GetActiveTenant")]
        public Tenant GetActiveTenant()
        {
            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            return tenantStore.Query().Where(x => x.Active == true).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

However when trying to use this endpoint, I get this error

> DocumentQueryException: Query expression is invalid, expression
>   https://cosmosdb-app-centralus.documents.azure.com/dbs/ToDoList/colls/tenants.Where(x
>   => (x.Active == True)).FirstOrDefault() is unsupported. Supported expressions are 'Queryable.Where', 'Queryable.Select' &
>   'Queryable.SelectMany'
>   *emphasized text*

I am using cosmonaut nuget package.

The only document I have in the collection:

```
{
    "ClientId": "aaaaaaaa-4817-447d-9969-e81df29c813d",
    "ClientSecret": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/esrQib6r7FAGd0=",
    "TenantDomainUrl": "abc.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SiteCollectionTestUrl": "https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1",
    "Active": true,
    "id": "d501acc6-6b63-4f0f-9782-1473af469b56",
    "_rid": "kUZJAOPekgAEAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/kUZJAA==/colls/kUZJAOPekgA=/docs/kUZJAOPekgAEAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00002602-0000-0000-0000-5b69fe790000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1533673081
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Cosmonaut's ReadMe page states](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#quering-for-entities-using-linq), you should be using the `Async` method extensions for Cosmonaut because they will go properly though the SDK's async flow.

For example in your case, you should change your code to `await tenantStore.Query().Where(x => x.Active == true).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

PS: You should also consider adding the `[JsonAttribute("id")]` attribute to your `Id` property. Even though it's not needed, it is recommended especially if you want to do querying based on the `Id`.